# Why is Google Plus not showing my posts from the past 8 months?

Tags: google+, google-my-business

Initially, I received feedback from an employee that when they opened the G+ company page on their iPhone browser, the last posts showing were from 8 months ago, even though we are actually posting weekly.

I could not re-create this problem on an iPhone or Android, but I see it happening when you open the G+ page in incognito mode: https://plus.google.com/+Petrocohen
You will see that the last post on the page was made in March (almost 40 weeks ago)
Now if you look at the same page in regular mode (not incognito), you will see a lot more recent posts.

I called Google My Business support and they were not able to help. They suggested I send feedback through the page and wait until someone gets back to me. I did this about a week ago and no one got back to me.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on and how it can be fixed?

Of course, clients probably won't look at the page in incognito but if this problem arises on my coworker's iPhone then it can happen on other people's phones as well.

Thank you!!!
Lucia